# How do I get jest to ignore the fairly common `debug` node package?

Tags: jestjs

I've got a node js module that looks like this

```
"use strict";

var debug = require('debug')('foo');

var Foo = function() {
  this.x = 123;
  debug("init");
};

module.exports = Foo;
```

And my test looks like this

```
jest.dontMock('../lib/foo');
jest.dontMock('debug');

describe('footest', function() {
 it('checks the foo', function() {
   var Foo = require('../lib/foo');
   var foo = new Foo();
   expect(foo.x).toBe(123);
 });
});
```

But when I run jest with

```
node node_modules/jest-cli/bin/jest.js
```

I get

```
Found 1 matching tests...
 FAIL  __tests__/foo-test.js (0.02s)
? footest › it checks the foo
  - TypeError: /Users/gregg/src/jest-test/lib/foo.js: /Users/gregg/src/jest-test/node_modules/debug/node.js: Cannot read property 'buffer' of undefined
      at Socket.self [as bytesWritten] (net.js:688:8)
      at _getMetadata (/Users/gregg/src/jest-test/node_modules/jest-cli/src/lib/moduleMocker.js:279:49)
      at _getMetadata (/Users/gregg/src/jest-test/node_modules/jest-cli/src/lib/moduleMocker.js:286:23)
      at _getMetadata (/Users/gregg/src/jest-test/node_modules/jest-cli/src/lib/moduleMocker.js:279:27)
      at _getMetadata (/Users/gregg/src/jest-test/node_modules/jest-cli/src/lib/moduleMocker.js:279:27)
      at Object.module.exports.getMetadata (/Users/gregg/src/jest-test/node_modules/jest-cli/src/lib/moduleMocker.js:388:20)
      at Loader._generateMock (/Users/gregg/src/jest-test/node_modules/jest-cli/src/HasteModuleLoader/HasteModuleLoader.js:280:56)
      at Loader.requireMock (/Users/gregg/src/jest-test/node_modules/jest-cli/src/HasteModuleLoader/HasteModuleLoader.js:782:43)
      at Loader.requireModuleOrMock (/Users/gregg/src/jest-test/node_modules/jest-cli/src/HasteModuleLoader/HasteModuleLoader.js:897:17)
      at /Users/gregg/src/jest-test/node_modules/debug/node.js:6:11
      at Object.runContentWithLocalBindings (/Users/gregg/src/jest-test/node_modules/jest-cli/src/lib/utils.js:309:17)
      at Loader._execModule (/Users/gregg/src/jest-test/node_modules/jest-cli/src/HasteModuleLoader/HasteModuleLoader.js:243:9)
      at Loader.requireModule (/Users/gregg/src/jest-test/node_modules/jest-cli/src/HasteModuleLoader/HasteModuleLoader.js:879:10)
      at Loader.requireModuleOrMock (/Users/gregg/src/jest-test/node_modules/jest-cli/src/HasteModuleLoader/HasteModuleLoader.js:899:17)
      at /Users/gregg/src/jest-test/lib/foo.js:3:13
      at Object.runContentWithLocalBindings (/Users/gregg/src/jest-test/node_modules/jest-cli/src/lib/utils.js:309:17)
      at Loader._execModule (/Users/gregg/src/jest-test/node_modules/jest-cli/src/HasteModuleLoader/HasteModuleLoader.js:243:9)
      at Loader.requireModule (/Users/gregg/src/jest-test/node_modules/jest-cli/src/HasteModuleLoader/HasteModuleLoader.js:879:10)
      at Loader.requireModuleOrMock (/Users/gregg/src/jest-test/node_modules/jest-cli/src/HasteModuleLoader/HasteModuleLoader.js:899:17)
      at Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/gregg/src/jest-test/__tests__/foo-test.js:7:14)
      at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
```

How do I get jest to ignore the debug package and why does it appear to be making a mock when I told it not to?

Answer (score 3):

Right now there is a bug in jest 0.1.18 (being fixed [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/122), documented [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/83)) where core node modules cannot be ignored from being mocked.

Once the pull request is accepted by facebook, this problem should go away.

Until then, you can point your package.json to the repo of the fix:

```
"jest-cli": "git://github.com/adaschevici/jest.git#cf4c6ff97d7009ff8627dd7d3a59cfeff1f3c8b8"
```

which should resolve that issue.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happens is because `jest.dontMock('debug');` will only prevent mocking the root file of the debug module, while all other internals will still be mocked.

One possible solution could be to prevent mocking debug library using `unmockedModulePathPatterns` configuration option:

In package.json:

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  ...
  "jest": {
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": ["/node_modules/debug"]
  },
}
```

Comment: The pull request above didn't solve the issue for me; this is actually the only solution that worked for me.

Comment: I have the same issue but these solutions didn't help me :/

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your test file, [try this](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/77#issuecomment-54869873):

```
    jest.autoMockOff();
```

Then manually mock files with `jest.mock(..)`

---

Update: There's [a fix](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/77#issuecomment-72997939) that doesn't require you turn off auto mocking. tldr; add `debug`, `tty`, and `net` to `jest.unmockedModulePathPatterns` in `package.json`